# What is _messengerUrlHandler in Facebook Messenger iOS?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I get 'Use of undeclared identifier' error for _messengerUrlHandler when I do everything on the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios

Is it something I should define?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I think it is just a variable that is declared globally, probably as a property.  It's an instance of FBSDKMessengerURLHandler.

On considering it a bit further, I think this variable is supposed to contain the class that you write that implements FBSDKMessengerURLHandler.  You can't just instantiate it, because it is an abstract class.  Instead you must derive a class from it and implement code for the functions in the abstract class.